# Batch file for compiling and running java files?

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to create a drag and drop shortcut for compiling and running java files, rather than a command line interface. I'm thinking, I will create two batch files. But, what do I write to make the batch files use javac.exe or java.exe on what ever java files are dropped onto the batch files?

For the compiler batch file:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin     
javac [what goes here?]    
pause
```

For the run java batch file:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin
java [what goes here?]
pause
```

Comment: What goes there is exactly the same as what you would type manually on the command line to compile and run your Java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother; you would find these batch files useful for about one day. After that, your Java programs will contain multiple `*.java` files and depend on various `*.jar` files. Learn to use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), which can handle build processes from the simplest to the most complex.

But for completeness, the files DnD'd onto a batch file are available as if they were passed as arguments to the batch file at the command line, so your "[what goes here?]" is "%1", or, if you anticipate multiple files, "%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9" .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a single file [this script](https://code.google.com/p/dosrunjava/downloads/list) will be useful.